# Green thing from matrix showing up on my VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[Screenshot of the green thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1D2CN.png)

I was just coding my way changing through tabs and I see this. What could be the issue? This is Win 10.

Comment: Well all I see are blondes and brunettes, whats the problem?

Comment: @Overbryd it obstructs the code, difficult to read. Well speaking as of now, its gone. But better know the issue to fix it.